# Testing whether the cost-cutting measures seem to be working at the $5\%$ significance level

Tags: probability, statistics

Experience in investigating insurance claims shows that the average cost to process a claim is approximately normally distributed with a mean of $80$ dollars. New cost-cutting measures were started and a sample of $25$ claims was tested. The sample mean of the costs to process these claims was $76\%$ and the sample standard deviation of the costs was $\$10$. We would like to test whether the cost-cutting measures seem to be working at the $5\%$ significance level.

State the null and alternative hypotheses for this test. Here is the $t$-distribution table

$$\begin{array}{r|cccccccccccc}
\text{cum. prob} & t_{.60} & t_{.76} & t_{.80} & t_{.85} & t_{.90} & t_{.95} & t_{.975} & t_{.99} & t_{.995} & t_{.999} & t_{.9995} \\ 
\text{one-tail} & 0.50 & 0.25 & 0.20 & 0.15 & 0.10 & 0.05 & 0.025 & 0.01 & 0.005 & 0.001 & 0.0005 \\ 
\text{two-tails} & 1.00 & 0.50 & 0.40 & 0.30 & 0.20 & 0.10 & 0.05 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.002 & 0.001\\ \hline
\text{df} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & &\\ 
 1 & 0.000 & 1.000 & 1.376 & 1.963 & 3.078 & 6.314 & 12.71 & 31.82 & 63.66 & 318.31 & 636.62\\ 
 2 & 0.000  & 0.816 & 1.061 & 1.386 & 1.886 & 2.920 & 4.303 & 6.965 & 9.925 & 22.327 & 31.559\\ 
 3 & 0.000  & 0.765 & 0.978 & 1.250 & 1.638 & 2.353 & 3.182 & 4.541 & 5.841 & 10.215 & 12.924 \\
 4 & 0.000  & 0.741 & 0.941 & 1.190 & 1.533 & 2.132 & 2.776 & 3.747 & 4.604 & 7.173 & 8.610\\ 
 5 & 0.000  & 0.727 & 0.920 & 1.156 & 1.476 & 2.015 & 2.571 & 3.365 & 4.032 & 5.893 & 6.869\\\hline 
\color{blue}{6} &  0.000 & 0.718 &  0.906 & 1.134 &  1.440 &  1.943 &  2.447 &  3.143 &  3.707 &  5.208 &  5.959\\
\color{blue}{7} & 0.000  & 0.711 &  0.896 & 1.119 &  1.415 & 1.895 &  2.365 &  2.998 &  3.499 &  4.785 & 5.408\\ 
\color{blue}{8} &  0.000  &  0.706 &  0.889 & 1.108 &  1.397 & 1.860 &  2.306 & 2.896 & 3.355 &  4.501 &  5.041\\ 
\color{blue}{9} & 0.000  &  0.703 &  0.883 &  1.100 &  1.383 &  1.833 &  2.262 &  2.821 &  3.250 &  4.297 &  4.781\\ 
\color{blue}{10} &  0.000  & 0.700 & 0.879 & 1.093 & 1.372 & 1.812 & 2.228 & 2.764 & 3.169 & 4.144 & 4.587\\\hline
 11 & 0.000  & 0.609 & 0.876 & 1.088 & 1.363 & 1.796 & 2.201 & 2.718 & 3.106 & 4.025 & 4.437\\ 
 12 & 0.000 & 0.695 & 0.873 & 1.083 & 1.356 & 1.782 & 2.179 & 2.681 & 3.055 & 3.930 & 4.318\\ 
 13 & 0.000  & 0.694 & 0.870 & 1.079 & 1.350 & 1.771 &  2.160 & 2.650 & 3.012 & 3.852 & 4.221\\ 
 14 & 0.000  & 0.692 & 0.868 & 1.076 & 1.345 & 1.761 & 2.145 & 2.624 & 2.977 & 3.787 & 4.140\\ 
 15 & 0.000  & 0.691 & 0.866 & 1.074 & 1.341 & 1.753 & 2.131 & 2.602 & 2.947 & 3.733 & 4.073\\\hline 
\color{blue}{16} & 0.000 & 0.690 & 0.865 & 1.071 & 1.337 & 1.746 & 2.120 & 2.583 & 2.921 & 3.686 & 4.015\\
 \color{blue}{17} &0.000  & 0.689 & 0.863 & 1.069 & 1.333 & 1.740 & 2.110 & 2.567 & 2.898 & 3.646 & 3.965\\ 
\color{blue}{18} & 0.000  & 0.688 & 0.862 & 1.067 & 1.330 & 1.734 & 2.101 & 2.552 & 2.878 & 3.610 & 3.922\\ 
\color{blue}{19} &0.000  & 0.688 & 0.861 & 1.066 & 1.328 & 1.729 & 2.093 & 2.539 & 2.861 & 3.579 & 3.883\\ 
\color{blue}{20} & 0.000  & 0.687 & 0.860 & 1.064 & 1.325 & 1.725 & 2.086 & 2.528 & 2.845 & 3.552 & 3.850\\\hline
 21 & 0.000  & 0.686 & 0.859 & 10.63 & 1.323 & 1.721 & 2.080 & 2.518 & 2.831 & 3.527 & 3.819\\ 
 22 & 0.000  & 0.686 & 0.858 & 1.061 & 1.321 & 1.717 & 2.074 & 2.508 & 2.819 & 3.505 & 3.792\\ 
 23 & 0.000  & 0.685 & 0.858 & 1.060 & 1.319 & 1.714 & 2.069 & 2.500 & 2.807 & 3.485 & 3.768\\ 
 24 & 0.000  & 0.685 & 0.857 & 10.59 & 1.318 & 1.711 & 2.604 & 2.492 & 2.797 & 3.467 & 3.745\\
 25 & 0.000  & 0.684 & 0.856 & 1.058 & 1.316 & 1.708 & 2.060 & 2.485 & 2.787 & 3.450 & 3.7325\\\hline 
\color{blue}{26} & 0.000  & 0.684 & 0.856 & 1.058 & 1.315 & 1.706 & 2.056 & 2.479 & 2.779 & 3.435 & 3.707\\ 
\color{blue}{27} & 0.000  & 0.684 & 0.855 & 1.057 & 1.314 & 1.703 & 2.052 & 2.473 & 2.771 & 3.421 & 3.690\\ 
\color{blue}{28} & 0.000  & 0.683 & 0.855 & 1.056 & 1.313 & 1.701 & 2.048 & 2.467 & 2.763 & 3.408 & 3.674\\ 
\color{blue}{29} & 0.000  & 0.683 & 0.853 & 1.055 & 1.311 & 1.699 & 2.045 & 2.462 & 2.756 & 3.396 & 3.659\\
\color{blue}{30} & 0.000  & 0.683 & 0.854 & 1.055 & 1.310 & 1.697 & 2.042 & 2.457 & 2.750 & 3.385 & 3.646\\\hline 
40 & 0.000  & 0.681 & 0.851 & 1.050 & 1.303 & 1.684 & 2.021 & 2.423 & 2.704 & 3.307 & 3.551\\ 
60 & 0.000  & 0.679  & 0.848 & 1.045 & 1.296 & 1.671 & 2.000 & 2.380 & 2.660 & 3.232 & 3.460\\ 
80 & 0.000  & 0.677 & 0.845 & 1.042 & 1.290 & 1.660 & 1.984 & 2.364 & 2.626 & 3.174 & 3.390\\ 
100 & 0.000  & 0.675 & 0.842 & 1.037 & 1.282 &  1.646 & 1.962 & 2.330 & 2.581 & 3.098 & 3.300\\
1000 & 0.000  & 0.674 & 0.842 & 1.036 & 1.282 & 1.645 & 1.960 & 2.326 & 2.576 & 3.090 & 3.291\\\hline
\color{blue}{\text{z}} & 0.000  & 0.674 & 0.842 & 1.036 & 1.282 & 1.645 & 1.960 & 2.326 & 2.576 & 3.090 & 3.291\\\hline
\text{Confidence Level} & 0\% & 50\% & 60\% & 70\% & 80\% & 90\% & 95\% & 98\% & 99\% & 99.8\% & 99.9\%\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Do you have a question of your own, or are you passing on to us a question written by someone other than yourself by just copying it?  Phrasing a question in a manner suitable for assigning homework is frowned upon here.

Comment: No sir this not like that. I did solve that question with the help of my teacher but i need to know the exact procedure of it. So could u please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of saying "the average cost to process a claim is approximately normally distributed with a mean of 80 dollars" you should have said "the cost to process a claim is approximately normally distributed with a mean of 80 dollars", letting the word "mean" be the only reference to averages.

The null hypothesis would be that the cost-cutting measures had no effect, so that that mean is still at least 80 dollars.  The alternative hypothesis were effective, so that the mean is now lower than that.

Generally a null hypothesis is something presumed true until statistical evidence indicates otherwise.

Comment: H0: µ = 80 -->null hypothesis...
 H1: µ < 80 -->alternative hypothesis... So is that correct Sir?

Comment: Yes. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: How can we test the critical value for this test Sir?

Comment: I think that Critical value for a one-tailed test (the alternative hypothesis shows a specific direction) can be found using a z-table at .05 level of significance. But i am not sure how to do that. Am i correct in this sir?

Comment: You can use $T=\dfrac{\bar x - 80}{S/\sqrt{n}}$ as a test statistic, where $n=25$ is the sample size, $S=10$ is the sample standard deviation, and $\bar x=76$ is the sample mean.  If the null hypothesis is true this should have a t-distribution with $24$ degrees of freedom.  So you would reject the null hypothesis if $T<c$ where $\Pr(T<c\mid\text{null})=0.05$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Sir can you help me out with the critical value Tc from the table i attached. The test statistic comes out to -2

Comment: 1.990<tc <2. Is that rite sir? and shouldn't we accept the null hypothesis if T<c sir?

Comment: I'm getting $\Pr(T<-1.710882)\approx 0.05$, so $H_0$ would be rejected because $-2<-1.170882$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Sir did you found that critical value using T-distribution method? and first you wrote -1.71 then u wrote -1.17. which one is correct?

Comment: The second one was a typo; I meant $1.71$. ${}\qquad{}$